# Escape Character as Part of the Exact Phrase - Full Text T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping, full-text-search, ssms

SSMS on SQL Server 2012 - full text enabled

I have seen a few escape character questions here but not the example I was looking for.  I have an exact term that I am trying to find that NEEDs to return the escape character as part of the phrase.

I want to find "ABC-123" but I am only finding "ABC" phrases.  I've been playing with it for a while and can't get it right. The closest guess I have so far is the below, but I am still getting hits that are missing "ABC-123" and only have the "ABC" phrase. This seems simple, but I can't seem to find it.

Thank you for looking into this for me.

Code, best guess (but incorrect):

```
DECLARE @Term NVARCHAR(100);
SET @Term = N'ABC-123'; 

SELECT *
FROM DB.schema.table
WHERE CONTAINS (column_name, @Term);
```

Comment: Please can you provide a bit more information on this? Some sample data would be very helpful. Also, is there a particular reason you are looking at T-SQL for this?

Comment: T-SQL as I understood it was just Transnational SQL.  Perhaps my word choice is off.  I am simply trying to return only note phrases with the exact content in the phrase via a query in SSMS.  I can try to mock up a table, but the actual data is confidential and cannot be made public.  Hence the cryptic "ABC-123" phrase.

Comment: Yes please, it can be example data but needs to be a true representation of the real system, so give a fair example if you can't provide the actual data. Just a few rows should be enough. Also, table schema please so we can understand what you are working with. FYI, I've just tested your example script and it works fine for me, so it would be good to see the rest of your set up to be able to help properly.

Comment: Hmmm, that may be tricky.  Perhaps I'm reaching a dead end.  The one thing I can say is that the column has datatype varbinary(max).

Comment: Try [`sys.dm_fts_parser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-parser-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2016). Although documented as SS2016 or later, it works on SS2008R2.

Comment: I believe that I do not have permission to run the above function.

Comment: It is fairly straight forward if you had a `VARCHAR` column but as you are working with a `VARBINARY` it's clearly a different story. [this might help you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/create-and-manage-full-text-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)